# Refactor read_excel result using python

Tags: python

I'm working on small project using Python i try to refactor my pd.read_excel() result but i get only the last row in my data variable:

this is my code :

```
@action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
def bulkImport(self, request, pk=None):
    file_uploaded = request.FILES.get('file')
    context = pd.read_excel(file_uploaded, engine='openpyxl')
    data = {}
    for column in context:
        for b in context[column].tolist():
            data[column] = b
            
    print(data)
```

Native read_excel() result :

```
{
    "name": [
        "amine",
        "bill"
    ],
    "company": [
        "bouhaddi",
        "microsoft"
    ],
    "email": [
        "ab@dothostia.com",
        "bill@microsoft.com"
    ],
    "phone": [
        43822510594,
        559485556555
    ],
    "adress": [
        "3820 albert st",
        "new york"
    ]
}
```

Expected Result :

```
{
    'name' : 'value',
    'phone' : 'value',
    'email' : 'value',
    'company' : 'value',
    'adress' : 'value',
},
{
    'name' : 'value',
    'phone' : 'value',
    'email' : 'value',
    'company' : 'value',
    'adress' : 'value',
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context={
    "name": [
        "amine",
        "bill"
    ],
    "company": [
        "bouhaddi",
        "microsoft"
    ],
    "email": [
        "ab@dothostia.com",
        "bill@microsoft.com"
    ],
    "phone": [
        43822510594,
        559485556555
    ],
    "adress": [
        "3820 albert st",
        "new york"
    ]
}

data=[{k:v[i]  for k,v in context.items() } for i in range(2) ]
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'amine',
  'company': 'bouhaddi',
  'email': 'ab@dothostia.com',
  'phone': 43822510594,
  'adress': '3820 albert st'},
 {'name': 'bill',
  'company': 'microsoft',
  'email': 'bill@microsoft.com',
  'phone': 559485556555,
  'adress': 'new york'}]
```

Using `list comprehension` and `dictionary comprehension` can give you the two dicts within a list

Comment: please can you give me a real example :) using my function if possible

Comment: data is empty when i print

Comment: I modified your data variable because there are many unknowns for me like `columns`...

Comment: i used your code but there is no result in data :(

Comment: print(data)    is empty

Comment: you did also range(2)  but we don't know how many rows we can have in our excel doc :)

Comment: you could use `len` that intutive

Comment: can you just write me an example please, because im new in python i will really appreciate

Comment: your` context` == my `data` variable guess that's the confusion

Comment: using your code we get the same old result

Comment: you can try by your self :)

Comment: God bless you man,   it work fine now can you please explain to me the loop, 
i'm coming from PHP world,   so your syntax is clean and little complicated for me

Comment: `dictionary comprehension` creates new dict `context.items()` produces list of tuples ..i iterated over it..but there is a list in `values` so we need to iterate over it also ..so two for loops